# $("#id") only selects the first element but $("div#id") selects both?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>

<body>

<div id='mydiv'>Hello, buddy.</div>
<div id='mydiv'>Hello, friend.</div>

</body>
```

When in JQuery, if I `$('#mydiv')` it will select only the first div, BUT if I do `$('div#mydiv')` it will select all of them.

I understand that specifying the element as well as the id, it will prevent from selecting other elements that have the same id but are not divs.

Isn't this a bug? Shouldn't `$('#mydiv')` select all elements which id is 'mydiv'?

Comment: The bug is in your HTML. You should never have more than one element with the same ID; JavaScript's `getElementById` assumes that there is only one such match. This is one example of the unpredictable behavior that can result.

Comment: Please refrain from accusations of bugs in libraries (especially those that are *well-vetted*) without extensive testing and supporting evidence.

Comment: @Blazemonger I would like to disagree on  "The bug is in your HTML. You should never have more than one element with the same ID". There are cases where more than one element with same ID can exist. For example: I may have a main page which takes an input (id="#name") for getting a person's name. A modal, can also appear in front of the main page, which can also take the same input (id="#name"). So the point is, in the main page as well as the modal, the code is being reused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Explanation for jQuery

Also, in your case, jQuery should select only one element, and the first element for `ID`. Since you have also given `div`, it uses `getElementsByTagName`, and matches the attribute with ID. So, it returns all the instances. Please correct me if I am wrong.

#### Suggestion

According to web standards, the `id` attribute must be unique. So, each element should have unique ID. If you want to use things for multiple elements, you have classes.

Also, your HTML won't validate, if you have multiple IDs.

Also, from the [XHTML 1.0 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10)

> In XML, fragment identifiers are of
> type ID, and there can only be a
> single attribute of type ID per
> element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the
> id attribute is defined to be of type
> ID. In order to ensure that XHTML 1.0
> documents are well-structured XML
> documents, XHTML 1.0 documents MUST
> use the id attribute when defining
> fragment identifiers on the elements
> listed above. See the HTML
> Compatibility Guidelines for
> information on ensuring such anchors
> are backward compatible when serving
> XHTML documents as media type
> text/html.

Comment: It could also be that it uses `querySelectorAll` which also returns both elements (surprisingly for me, even `querySelectorAll('#mydiv')` returned both elements in Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug at all... IDs (#myId) are not supposed to be used in multiple instances. That's why we have classes (.myClasses).

So, you can use classes as much as you want. But IDs are always unique for each HTML page. You may have one ID showing up in many different pages, but always as a unique ID.

Answer (score 2):

`#mydiv` is likely optimized to use `getElementById`, which is described in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html) as:

> Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this id.

Usually the first element with such an ID is returned though.