# Rails 5: Trying to render divs with a single partial but keep the div class unique so that JQuery doesn't fire on all partials

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

A bit of a confusing title.

I am trying to implement a bit of a reddit like comment system. So that you can view a `Post` and add a `Comment` to it which is polymorphic. Or, comment on another `Comment`.

My view looks like so:

```
<h2>Post:</h2>
<div class="well">
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @post.title %>
  </p>
<% if @post.description %>
  <p>
    <strong>Description:</strong>
    <%= @post.description %>
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>

<% if current_user %>
  <%= render "shared/comment_form" %>
<% else %>
  <p>Log in to add comments</p>
<% end %>

<% if @post.comments.any? %>
  <%= render "shared/comment_list" %> # Another comment_form inside of this partial
<% else %>
  <p>No comments yet</p>
<% end %>
```

Inside of `comment_list` is another rendering of `comment_form` so that you can comment on a comment:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<ul>
  <% @post.comments.each do |co| %>
    <li><%= co.body %></li>
    <%= render "shared/comment_form" if current_user %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Finally, my comment form itself:

```
<div id="comment-form" class="form-group">
  <%= form_for @comment, remote: true, url: post_comments_path(@post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, required: true, rows: 5, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value => @post.class.name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<span id="add-comment">Add a comment</span>
```

And the Jquery code that acts on the `comment_form`:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#comment-form").hide();
  $('#add-comment').click( function() {
    $("#comment-form").fadeToggle("fast");
    ($("#add-comment").text() === "Cancel") ? $("#add-comment").text("Add comment") : $("#add-comment").text("Hide");
  });
});
```

My question is:

How could I separate these divs so that Jquery doesn't fire on all instances of `id="comment-form`? I would like to pass in an erb tag like <%= @post.class.name %><%= @post.id %>, but again, keep the variable universal. Then, how could I implement that unique id name in my JQuery code.

Edit: I got one part of my question solved. I left the rest of what I wasn't able to do up for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `prev()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comment-form').hide();

    $('.add-comment').click( function(event) {
    // Store the button which has just been clicked on a variable
    var eventTarget = $(event.target);

    // Find the previous element with the #comment-form and id and toggle it
    eventTarget.prev('.comment-form').fadeToggle('fast');

    // Use the eventTarget Again
    (eventTarget.text() === 'Cancel') ? eventTarget.text('Add comment') : eventTarget.text('Cancel');
  });
});
```

You can see this in action here: http://codepen.io/rebagliatte/pen/MbKNJv

Comment: I appreciate the help. However, using that code doesn't seem to have an effect on my page.

http://imgur.com/a/cXeS8

The form for the post itself will work as expected but the `Add a comment` link for the comments themselves isn't functional at all. How would be the best way to go about debugging that?

Comment: You can debug this with Chrome dev tools by placing a `debugger;` line anywhere on your javascript code.

Comment: Also, here's a little proof of concept: http://codepen.io/rebagliatte/pen/MbKNJv. Please note I've replaced your id with classes since [IDs must be unique per page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410693/id-only-selects-the-first-element-but-divid-selects-both). Let me know if this helps!

Comment: sorry I am a bit late. I just got around to reading your solution. I totally spaced the fact that I was using ID's. I had initially intended to use that form in one area before I made it DRY. You solution works awesome and I have marked it correct. Thank you