# multiples buttons that share one javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am using a foreach loop to load data from mysql table using php.

Now I have a button with a javascript function next to each foreeach set of data to display the data.

The problem is, the button only works on the very first fetched data in the foreach loop. I am not sure what the problem is?

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/7qL2osp5/

I am using this script btw

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bigger(){
        document.getElementById("approvals-data-box").style.width="95%";
        document.getElementById("actual-data").style.display="block";
  }

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$("#id") only selects the first element but $("div#id") selects both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410693/id-only-selects-the-first-element-but-divid-selects-both)

Comment: not a duplicate, as this one is pure js and not jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is used for one specific element.  You can only have one element with the same `id`.

What you need to do is give them all different `id`s and then pass in the id to the function.  You also need classes for the styling.

IDs are for specific elements.  Classes are for element types.

Here's a working version:

https://jsfiddle.net/7qL2osp5/1/

In CSS, you use the `.` for classes and the `#` for `id`s.  This may be a good time to try to learn jQuery since you're just starting out.

Comment: Sorry.  I provided the wrong link.  It's updated now.

Comment: I also found `overflow: none;` and `white-space:nowrap;` made it look prettier.  https://jsfiddle.net/7qL2osp5/2/

Comment: Won't it be better passing `this` inside `bigger()` than creating so many IDs and passing numbers in each of them?

Comment: Yes, but for that you really should use jQuery because jQuery lets you search the descendants of elements.  `$(this).children('.actual-data').with ...`

Comment: Believe me, jQuery is a lot easier to learn, though, I give you kudos for now knowing what's happening underneath the hood with `getElementById` and `getElementsByClass`

Comment: @Bluebaron using jQuery because it can search descendants is just wrong, javascript can too... Although I just suggested using jQuery too, but all what jQuery does javascript can do it...

Comment: It takes a lot more work to do that in JavaScript, though it can be done. It's not simple at that point.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you are not using unique IDs... IDs are meant to be unique. The browser will always return the first they find, hence why you always get the first row.

Try using the event's target, which will be the clicked button, and find its corresponding siblings.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){
if(e.target.className == "clickme"){
 e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
});
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><button class="clickme">Click me</button> A</li>
 <li><button class="clickme">Click me</button> B</li>
 <li><button class="clickme">Click me</button> C</li>
 <li><button class="clickme">Click me</button> D</li>
 <li><button class="clickme">Click me</button> E</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a minimal example. The script attaches an event to the body, and triggers the effect only if the element's class is "clickme". Then we take the parent of that button and change it's background color.

Note that it is a very minimal example and that is not a very good way to do it. For example if you add another class to your buttons, it will not work... I'd suggest you use jQuery as it will make things a lot easier for you to play with events.

Comment: hmm i see what you're saying, ive tried the event approach but I am unable to get it working. do you mind showing me an example please?

Comment: there you go. Added a very minimalistic example that should express what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I've using pure javascript, but after seeing how simple jquery makes it, I will reconsider and learn jq. amazing stuff thanks again

Comment: jQuery is still javascript! But it abstracts a lot... without counting the fact that every browser is different, you'll learn more using the proper tools I think, as you'll be more focused on your task and not just fighting weird behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique, you should use `class`. You need to pass it like `onmouseover="bigger(this)"`, so that only selector is considered. Below is an updated code:

```css
.approvals-data-box {
  width: 00px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  -webkit-transition: 400ms linear;
  -moz-transition: 400ms linear;
  -o-transition: 400ms linear;
  -ms-transition: 400ms linear;
  transition: 400ms linear;
  border: 1px dotted transparent;
  margin: 2px;
}

.actual-data {
  display: none;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#style-button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fetched data from database</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Reveal Button</th>
    <th>Actual Data</th>
  </tr>
  <!--------------------------------------------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div onmouseover="bigger(this)" id="style-button">hover me to reveal data 1</div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div class="approvals-data-box">
        <div class="actual-data">data 1</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--------------------------------------------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div onmouseover="bigger(this)" id="style-button">hover me to reveal data 2 (not working)</div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div class="approvals-data-box">
        <div class="actual-data">data 2</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--------------------------------------------->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div onmouseover="bigger(this)" id="style-button">hover me to reveal data 3 (not working)</div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div class="approvals-data-box">
        <div class="actual-data">data 3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function bigger(elem) {
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('approvals-data-box')[0].style.width = "95%";
    elem.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('actual-data')[0].style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but this expands the button itself rather than the actual data.

Comment: Ok. I have updated based on you requirements. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `getElementById` and non unique ids on your document. I see you have `id="approvals-data-box"` many times.

You should either assign unique ids or use a different type of selection (eg. `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to affect multiple elements.

Hint: Since you're generating your DOM with php, you can use the `uniqid()` function to append random content to your ids

Another approach would be using the element itself, without querying the DOM by applying something like `onclick="..."` which would use the event's target

Comment: Thanks for your help @fotis I've tried using something like this but its not working 

  var x = event.target;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Triggered by a " + x.tagName + " element";
}

Comment: If you change `onmouseover="bigger()"` to `onmouseover="bigger(this)"` you'll be getting the element as the first argument, if you also change to `onmouseover="bigger('#approvals-data-box-1 #actual-data'")` you'll get the target selector as the argument. You can then alter your `bigger` function to use the target accordingly. eg. `document.querySelector(target)`